# Python debugging - "not a list"

Tags: python, debugging

I wrote the following code:

```
def data_preprocessing_tree(data):
    data = data.split(';') # enumerate
    data = list(filter(lambda x: not ('..' in x or '//' in x), data)) # clean (noise removal)
    data = list(map(lambda x: x + 'txt' if x[len(x) - 1] == '.' else x, data)) # complete missing values

    data_new = list(map(lambda x: x.rsplit('/', 1) if '.' in x.rsplit('/', 1)[1] else x, data)) # not file?
    # data_file = list(map(lambda x: x[len(x) - 1] if '.' in x[len(x) - 1] else '', data_new))
    # data_file = list(filter(lambda x: '.' in x, data_file))
    data_dir = list(map(lambda x: x[:len(x) - 1] if '.' in x[len(x) - 1] else x, data_new)) # if last is file

    # print('{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n\n'.format(data_new, data_file, data_dir))
    print('{0}\n{1}\n\n'.format(data_new, data_dir))

    # data_dir = list(map(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) == list else x, data_dir))
    data_dir = list(map(lambda x: [x] if type(x) != list else x, data_dir))
    tmp = data_dir[:]
    data_dir = list(filter(lambda x: tmp.remove(x) is None and tmp.count(x) == 0, data_dir))

    print(data_dir)

    tmp = list(map(lambda x: data_dir[data_new.index(list([x[0]]))].append(x[1]) if type(x) == list else x, data_new))
```

It throws an exception on the last line, saying the given input is not a list.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "demo.py", line 21, in data_preprocessing_tree
    tmp = list(map(lambda x: data_dir[data_new.index(list([x[0]]))].append(x[1]) if type(x) == list else x, data_new))
  File "demo.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    tmp = list(map(lambda x: data_dir[data_new.index(list([x[0]]))].append(x[1]) if type(x) == list else x, data_new))
ValueError: ['/Users/someuser'] is not in list
```

The purpose is to transform a string like that:

```
"/Users/someuser/file.py;/tmp/download/file.zip;/tmp/download/file2.zip;/;/usr/local/bin;/User/someuser/file..py;/tmp/file."
```

into that:

```
[("/", ()), ("/tmp/download", ("file.zip", "file2.zip", “unknown.txt”)), ("/usr/local/bin", ()), ("/User/someuser/", ("file.py", “uknown.txt”))]
```

That is, a list of tuples, containing at the first element the directory, and the second will be another tuple, which will contain all the files in that location.

Currently, it is supposed to make it into a list of lists, which the first element of each inner list will be the location, and the rest will be the files.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use list comprehensions here?

Comment: Yes, for the love of everything that is holy use list comprehensions and not map with lambdas. It will tremendously improve the readability (and performance slightly) of your code.

Comment: Also, what is this: `lambda x: tmp.remove(x) is None and tmp.count(x) == 0` suppose to accomplish? It is super hacky regardless and is mixing mutations with a functional construct, map, which is poor style. It makes for confusing code, as is the case here.

Comment: `list.append` is in-place, it returns `None`. Split that mess into multiple lines, so you can actually debug it; put some `print`s in and figure out what's going on. Note also that it's staggeringly inefficient to do things like splitting the same string multiple times in the same way; do it once, *then* use the result. This also allows you to give the result a meaningful name, which might help explain what exactly your code is doing.

Comment: Also, you might want to work from the ground up: *first* make sure that you can build your desired list with the code you're using, one operation per line, using temporary variables.  *Then* reduce the logic to a single line.

Comment: @Prune or just keep the multiple lines...

Comment: Oh and please give a [mcve] including the actual traceback. I guess I should have opened with that. Once you get this working I'd strongly recommend a trip to [codereview.se].

Comment: To clearify, I must use map and filter, can't use loops and functions. That is why the code looks like that.

Comment: Why not? Your code is basically obfuscated, which makes debugging difficult and unpleasant for everyone. And even so it's not well thought-out; for example, `list([x[0]])` is just `[x[0]]` with a redundant conversion to the list it already is.

Comment: This is the demand. It just a college assignment.

Comment: Setting aside that `lambda` is using functions... I'm having a hard time understanding the why: can you elaborate on what you are supposed to be demonstrating?

Comment: Lambda is fine by them. I really don't know what is the perpuse behind it, beside forcing to use map and filter, and thinking hard on how to implement such a bizard thing using nothing but those built-in functions.

Comment: "is not a list." != " is not in list" Your exception doesn't match your original description. This is why it's really important to include the actual output, not what you think it said.

Answer (score 0):

The original data is received as a single string of file paths separated by ‘;'.

The process of building the tree is as follows:
1) Transform the data into a list of file paths as strings [split]

2) Remove any path from the list if it contains two dots (..) or lashes (//) consequentially [filter]

3) Append ‘txt’ to any file that doesn’t have an extension, i.e. ‘file.’ ---> ‘file.txt’ [map]

4) Obtain a set of directory paths, without files, i.e. [‘/tmp/download/file.zip’, ‘/tmp/download/file2.zip’, ‘/usr/local’] ---> [‘/tmp/download’, ‘/usr/local’] [map, join, split, rsplit]

5) Convert the list of paths into a list of tuples which contain directory path and the file name separately, i.e . [‘/tmp/download/file.zip’, ‘/tmp/download/file2.zip’, ‘/usr/local’] ---> [(‘/tmp/download’, 'file.zip'), (‘/tmp/download’, 'file2.zip), ('/usr/local', None)] [filter, map, join, split, rsplit]

6) For each path from the set of paths, create a tuple, where the first element is the path and the second element is a tuple containing all the file names from that given path, i.e. [‘/tmp/download’, ‘/usr/local’] and [(‘/tmp/download’, 'file.zip'), (‘/tmp/download’, 'file2.zip)] ---> [(‘/tmp/download’, (file.zip, file2.zip)),(‘/usr/local’, ())] [map, filter]

The steps and functions displayed above are guidelines only and are not mandatory to obtain the correct final answer.

**Signed,
Marina Litvak**